# Postgres pg_dump to Amazon Aurora

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-s3, database-migration, amazon-aurora

I have a 5TB Postgres database in a different account in a different region which I want to migrate to our account and region. The source is PostgreSQL 11.5 on EC2 (standard Linux Ubuntu). The destination would be Aurora postgres (serverless) in our account and region.  So this is a cross account and cross region transfer and import.

1. In the source account (US-West-2 region) create an S3 Bucket with cross region replication with appropriate role
2. From the source account, do the pg_dump to place the dump in an S3 above. Due to cross region replication the data will be copied over to the replication in US-East-2.
3. In the source account - Provision a destination account IAM user to access the source account S3 replication instance.
4. In the destination account we’ll create Aurora Postgres and import the data without having to bear the cross region data transfer.

I need help with the following.

1. Is S3 cross region replication eliminate the cross region pg_dump data migration cost since S3 replication is free and the data import in the destination will happen from S3 in the same region.
2. Does Aurora postgres (serverless) support pg_restore/import from aws cli.

Thanks in advance folks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use S3 to limit costs, you can do a pg_dump to s3, this is reasonable.

To migrate directly, I would recommend using [pgloader](https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

You can use it to migrate from one database to the other:

```
pgloader postgresql:///source postgresql:///destination
```

If you want to use `pg_restore` it should work but otherwise `psql -f dump.sql` also works.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Do you see any issue with the size of the database in my case. Is pg_restore a good approach for a database of size 5TB?

Comment: With such a large database, I think both options would work. `pg_restore` will take longer than `pgloader` but both will take very long anyway